# Test for seasonal, correlation and significance of peaks (maximum) evaluation in time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, statistical-significance, arima, seasonality

Studying two time series I believe they have a seasonal pattern, with well defined peaks, and are correlated to each other. I want to test them to get some statistical results.

A plot of both series is like:

[image: Plot of the two series]

The two series are available in CSV format at:

- MG: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2xv8j0ltg2mfro/mg.csv?dl=0
- BC: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfhma4616n1zoy8/bc.csv?dl=0

Visually we can see the correlation between the two series, having maximum peaks around october. The time series also seems to be seasonal.

However, the `decompose` function in R does not identify seasonal data. I tried [ARIMA](http://search.r-project.org/R/library/stats/html/arima.html) test, but I am not sure if I am using it right. I ask you for help in order to answer the following questions:

1. Is there a seasonal pattern in the time series? How to test it?
2. What is the best correlation test for these two time series? What will the result mean (i.e. practical implications)?
3. How to test the significance of the peaks in these series? Are they real peaks, meaning statically significant? How to quantify and describe them?

Comment: can u conform that the last 3 values ( periods 258-260) for MG are 100,56, and 57 as they appear to be inconsistent (outliers) with the first 257 values.

Comment: yes. they are outliers because of the season. the data is right.